# Unexplicable error in MATLAB 2014b

Tags: matlab

MATLAB 2014b is giving me this error. My script ended up with this colorful nonsense when I clicked to see where the error was from the command window.

[image]

Previously it was error of mismatching matrix elements. But this seems like a MATLAB error and not a bug in my code.

Any ideas?

Comment: It might be the damaged file in your filesystem. Can you open it with any text editor?

Comment: Oh really? I am running Ubuntu 14.04. I can open the scripts itself, the error happens when I click on the error link. The editor opens another script of the same name but with all the nonsense.

Comment: So what?? You don't think that file can be damaged or overwritten by something else? Open it with any text editor - if content is the same then why do you think it is a problem of matlab? It looks like some binary code to me. `The editor opens another script of the same name but with all the nonsense` this is what you have to start with... In recent Matlab files with functions are compiled, not with matlab scripting inside. Not all of them, but I saw a lot.

Comment: I saw that content of many function.m files in new Matlab is precompiled, so they do not have inside original code in a readable way. When is it executed, matlab's interpreter understands it, show the error message, but you will not see the normal code inside. When you click on error message, it will try to show you the  source even if the error is inside of Matlab's builtin function.

Comment: 'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: GLNXA64, Created on: Sat Oct 11 22:13:08 2014 ' This is listed up top. What does it mean? Anyhow the error message is new. Initially calling the function gave one error but now it gives another. 'he input character is not valid in MATLAB statements or expressions.
'

Comment: This is a .mat file, not a function, which is binary and it contains saved variables and their values. It should not show any error (if not damaged). http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/what-is-the-matlab-workspace.html `The input character is not valid in MATLAB statements or expressions.` it can not parse .mat file by some reasons, can not tell you exactly without seeing the code first. Or you have some symbols in command line-  Look here - http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MATLAB_Programming/Error_Messages

Comment: Well this is a bit beyond my knowledge. But from what I am getting is that the file system of my Ubuntu may be corrupt.

Comment: Show to code you are running, upload and give the link to .mat file causing errors - others needs something to reproduce an error. if you have this binary code in .m file, then, probably, this file was overwritten by .mat file (or function saving variables into .mat file). I can not tell when it happens and how - not enough information for that.

Comment: Hey I found my issue. So I was trying to save local function variables to the workspace but just ended up saving the function itself with data to different locations. My initial problem was I want to see how the matrices look like within the function because I have an indexing error.

Answer (score 0):

Restating what I said in the comments:

I found my issue. So I was trying to save local function variables to the workspace but just ended up saving the function itself with data to different locations. Hence I had several files of the same name and most them being corrupt.